# The probability of two samples of a waveform to be separated by certain amount

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to mathematically model the probability of observing a waveform crossing based on two of its samples. Im particular, I want to know the effect of the sampling frequency and phase on this. Unfortunately, my statistics is a bit underdeveloped for this at this time.

Here is how I have tried to formulate it as:

Say the first sample is defined by:

$X_1 = A~sin(\omega_ot)$

where $A$ is uniformally distributed between $-A_0$ and $+A_0$ and $\omega_ot$ has some <s>Gaussian distribution</s> Uniform distribution between $-\pi,\pi$. Amplitude is a random variable indicating that the amplitude modulated sequence is random and time is a random variable indicating no phase relationship between the sampling clock and the signal.

Similarly, $X_2 = A~sin(\omega_o(t+T_S))$ where $T_S$ is the sampling period between the two samples.

$T_s$, $T$ and $\omega_o$ are known constants.

Now I want the probability $P(X_1<-T~and~X_2>T) ~or~ P(X_1>T~and~X_2<-T)$

How can I proceed from here now and find the distribution?

EDIT 1: 
The restriction on $t$ being Gaussian is just made up as a starting point, perhaps assuming some other distribution such as $Uni(-\pi,\pi)$ will allow for easier analytical expressions?

EDIT 2: I realize what I want is not the same as $P(|X_1-X_2|>2T)$, so I have removed my attempt at the calculation.

Comment: Several questions / comments: (1) So $\omega_0, T_S, T$ are given constants? 
 (2) By symmetry, modeling $A \sim U(-A_0, +A_0)$ should be the same as modeling $A \sim U(0, A_0)$ which may be a more natural description since $A$ is an amplitude and normally non-negative. (3) $|X_1 - X_2| > 2T$ is _NOT_ the same as having one above $T$ and one below $-T$.  E.g. imagine $T$ is small compared to $A$, then $|X_1-X_2| > 2T$ could happen while both are above $T$.  So which condition do you actually want?  (4) IMHO the natural model for "random" $t$ is $\omega_0 t \sim U(-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are right and my attempt at rephrasing it as a subtraction of the random variables was wrong. I have edited the question. I have also made it clear I now assume the the phase is uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT / partial solution only.  Also, this Answer really needs a diagram, but I don't have any easy way to draw pictures... sorry!

First re-frame the problem a bit.  For ease of visualization we will only consider positive $A \sim U(0, A_0)$. You have a uniform-random phase $\theta = \omega_0 t \sim U(-\pi, \pi)$ and a given "phase offset" $\phi = \omega_0 T_S$.  And you want $\{\sin\theta, \sin(\theta + \phi)\}$ to be one above $T/A$ and one below $-T/A$.

For the rest, it is easier if we consider $\phi \in [0, \pi]$.  You can obviously bring it to $[-\pi, \pi]$ by just ignoring multiples of $2\pi$, and then you can also bring it to $[0, \pi]$ by conceptually swapping the roles of the two, which would change the sign of $\phi$, but doesn't affect the "one above, one below" criterion.

For a given value of the $T/A$ ratio, I would solve this geometrically.  Simply draw a unit circle and then two lines $y=\pm T/A$.  Then imagine rotating the pair of radii at angles $\theta, \theta + \phi$ and ask: what values of $\theta$ satisfy the "one above, one below" criterion?

This means the two radii must "straddle" the "band" $-{T\over A}\le y \le {T\over A}$.  First of all this is impossible if $T \ge A$ (the band covers the entire circle), so for now assume $T < A$.  The angle subtended by the band and including the positive $x$-axis (sorry I have no other way to describe it) is $\alpha = 2 \arcsin {T\over A}.$  If $\phi \le \alpha$, straddling is again impossible, whereas for $\phi > \alpha$, there is "leeway" of $\phi - \alpha$ as the pair of radii straddles the band on the $x>0$ side of the circle.  The straddling can also happen on the $x<0$ side, so the overall probability is

$$
\begin{align}
p(\phi, T, A) &= {2 (\phi - \alpha) \over 2 \pi} = {\phi - \alpha \over \pi} = {\phi - 2\arcsin {T\over A} \over \pi} && \text{ if } T < A \text{ and } \phi > \alpha\\
p(\phi, T, A) &= 0 && \text{ otherwise}
\end{align}
$$

---

UPDATE: OK, finally you want to integrate over $A \sim U(0, A_0)$, which of course has pdf $1/A_0$, so the overall answer is:

$$ {1 \over A_0} \int_0^{A_0} p(\phi, T, A)\, dA$$

To turn this into something more useful, we retain only the part where $p(\phi, T, A) > 0$, i.e. we retain the cases where (i) $T < A$ and (ii) $\phi > \alpha$.  Requirement (ii) can be rewritten as:

$$\phi > \alpha = 2 \arcsin {T\over A} \iff {T\over A} < \sin {\phi \over 2} \iff A > {T \over \sin {\phi \over 2}} = A_1$$

(Note: this first $\iff$ works because $\phi \in [0, \pi]$ and so ${\phi \over 2} \in [0, {\pi \over 2}]$, and in this latter range, the $\sin()$ function is strictly increasing.)

Since $A_1 \ge T$ always, this means requirement (ii) $A > A_1$ is strictly more stringent than requirement (i) $A > T$, and so the integral becomes:

$$ {1 \over A_0} \int_{T/\sin{\phi \over 2}}^{A_0} {\phi - 2\arcsin {T\over A} \over \pi}\, dA\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{assuming } A_1 = T/\sin{\phi \over 2} < A_0$$

I have no idea how to solve this in closed form, but luckily you said you only plan to evaluate it numerically!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! The geometrical interpretation really helped me understand this better. Could you please write out the integral you are referring to? I am not interested in the analytic expression, and will just do it numerically in MATLAB.

Comment: Also, now that I think about this more, i cant quite grasp how this geometrical interpretation works. When you say rotate the radii around together, that implies that the value of $\theta$ was same for both which might not necessarily be the case because each time $\theta$ could be different i.e $sin(\theta_1)$, $sin(\theta_2 + \phi)$?

Comment: I assumed you are taking $2$ samples time $T_S$ apart, and therefore angle $\phi = \omega_0 T_S$ apart.  You dont know the first sample's $\theta$, and the second sample's $\theta+\phi$, but you know for sure that they are $\phi$ apart, right?

Comment: Aah yes, sorry i was unnecessarily complicating things. Your right.

Comment: I tried the random phase only expression by making a simple statistical simulator in matlab and it agrees really well! Any pointers on how to formulate the final integral with random amplitude will be very helpful :)

Comment: Hope the update helps?  If we're all set, pls accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.